# Alphanumeric validator the Ñ and ñ characters y js form validator

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

How can I add in alphanumeric characters `Ñ` and `ñ`  in a form validator from [formvalidator.net](http://formvalidator.net/#default-validators)?

If I add `ñ` or `Ñ` using :

```
data-validation="alphanumeric" data-validation-allowing="ñÑ -_"
```

It doesn't work properly.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that particular jquery plugin doesn't support unicode at all.

Comment: This works for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vnjgA . Maybe you should add your entire code?